# Java Stripes Error

Tags: java, tomcat, web, stripes

So I am following the quick start guide on the Stripes website here:

http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Quick+Start+Guide

I have followed each step but when I try to view it I get the error message:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.Test.WebContent.index_jsp

type Exception report

message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.Test.WebContent.index_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.Test.WebContent.index_jsp) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.Test.WebContent.index_jsp
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.Test.WebContent.index_jsp
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.29 logs.
```

I don't really understand what is going wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are not building it right, make sure all dependencies are in the build path and if you exporting it, make sure they are also in the export and deploy path